# Magento 2 - Custom Grid Action 404 error Add Action Throws 404 Error

Tags: magento2, grid, custom, adminform, action

i Develop Simple Crude Operation Module That Throws 404

[image]

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Api\Data\AllsectionInterface" type="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection" />
    <preference for="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Api\AllsectionRepositoryInterface" type="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\AllsectionRepository" />

    <virtualType name="AllsectionGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\ResourceModel\Allsection\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="section_allsection_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\ResourceModel\Allsection\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\ResourceModel\Allsection\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">screen_layer_data</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">allsection_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\ResourceModel\Allnews</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <preference for="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Api\CustomInterface" type="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Api\Custom"/>
    <preference for="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Api\Data\CustomInterface" type="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Api\CustomData"/>

</config>
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/section_allsection_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_listing.section_allsection_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_listing.section_allsection_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">allsection_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Layer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="section_allsection_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AllsectionGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">layer_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">layer_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky type="xs:boolean">false</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="section/allsection/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="allsection_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="section/allsection/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">layer_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_listing.section_allsection_listing.allsection_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">section_allsection_listing.section_allsection_listing.allsection_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>layer_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="layer_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="category_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>category_name</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>category_name</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Category Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="layer_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>layer_name</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>layer_name</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Layer Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>


        <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection\Source\Status"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Created</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Modified</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AllsectionActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>layer_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Ui/Component/Listing/Column/AllsectionActions.php

```
       <?php
        
        namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
        
        use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
        use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
        use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
        use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
        
        /**
         * Class AllsectionActions
         */
        class AllsectionActions extends Column
        {
            /** Url path */
            const CMS_URL_PATH_EDIT = 'section/allsection/edit';
            const CMS_URL_PATH_DELETE = 'section/allsection/delete';
        
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
             */
            protected $urlBuilder;
        
            /**
             * @var string
             */
            private $editUrl;
        
            /**
             * @var Escaper
             */
            private $escaper;
        
            /**
             * @param ContextInterface $context
             * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
             * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
             * @param array $components
             * @param array $data
             * @param string $editUrl
             */
            public function __construct(
                ContextInterface $context,
                UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
                UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
                array $components = [],
                array $data = [],
                $editUrl = self::CMS_URL_PATH_EDIT
            ) {
                $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
                $this->editUrl = $editUrl;
                parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
            }
        
            /**
             * Prepare Data Source
             *
             * @param array $dataSource
             * @return array
             */
            public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
            {
                if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                    foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                        $name = $this->getData('name');
                        if (isset($item['layer_id'])) {
                            $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                                'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['layer_id' => $item['layer_id']]),
                                'label' => __('Edit')
                            ];
                            $title = $this->getEscaper()->escapeHtml($item['layer_name']);
                            $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                                'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::CMS_URL_PATH_DELETE, ['layer_id' => $item['layer_id']]),
                                'label' => __('Delete'),
                                'confirm' => [
                                    'title' => __('Delete %1', $title),
                                    'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete a %1 record?', $title)
                                ]
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
        
                return $dataSource;
            }
        
            /**
             * Get instance of escaper
             * @return Escaper
             * @deprecated 101.0.7
             */
            private function getEscaper()
            {
                if (!$this->escaper) {
                    $this->escaper = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Escaper::class);
                }
                return $this->escaper;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

what i am wrong?

> Controller/Adminhtml/AllSection/NewAction.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\Allsection;
    
    class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
         */
        protected $resultForwardFactory;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
        ) {
            $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
        
        /**
         * Authorization level
         *
         * @see _isAllowed()
         */
        protected function _isAllowed()
        {
            return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vrinsoft_Appscreens::save');
        }
    
        /**
         * Forward to edit
         *
         * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward $resultForward */
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            return $resultForward->forward('edit');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

> Controller/Adminhtml/AllSection/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\AllSection;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  protected $allSectionFactory;
  protected $allLayerFactory;
  protected $resultPageFactory;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\AllsectionFactory $allSectionFactory,
    \Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\AlllayerFactory $allLayerFactory
  ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->allSectionFactory = $allSectionFactory;
    $this->allLayerFactory = $allLayerFactory;
  }

  public function execute()
  {

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('All Screens Layers'));
    return $resultPage;

    // $allsection = $this->allSectionFactory->create();
    // $sectionCollection = $allsection->getCollection();
    
    // echo '<pre>';print_r($sectionCollection->getData());

    // $alllayer = $this->allLayerFactory->create();
    // $layerCollection = $alllayer->getCollection();

    // echo '<pre>';print_r($layerCollection->getData());
    
    //$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    //return $resultPage
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: can you post your controller too.

Comment: okay sure let me i post my controller code oky

Comment: I add my controller file in quation

Comment: what is your new action url

Comment: admin/section/allsection/new/key/0c71f9279a8cbd5c21fb6b3c4b3071efe170307d64d77e34266e050e271f97de/

Comment: @JayParmar as per your code the actions urls are 'section/allsection/edit', 'section/allsection/delete'. Where have you defined your new action url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your controller  file name and the action name you provided.
your action is

> section/allsection/edit/

or

> section/allsection/delete

While your controller file is

> Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\AllSection\Index

You will have to create your controller for these two actions like -

> Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\AllSection\Edit
> Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\AllSection\Delete

The url should follow the pattern

> module-route-name/controller-name/action-name/

Answer (score 1):

change your controller

namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\Allsection;

to

namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Controller\Adminhtml\AllSection;

Comment: do that but still not solve

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with the permission issue.

In NewAction.php file, you defined below

```
     /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vrinsoft_Appscreens::save');
    }
```

Could you confirm whether you mentioned authorisation correctly `Vrinsoft_Appscreens::save`

Also, you have defined the authorization in **acl.xml file**  in the file path

```
app/code/Vrinsoft/Appscreens/etc/acl.xml
```

If not, define it and check.