# Admin Page Error after login admin

Tags: error, magento2.4.3, 404-page

I got 404 error after login to admin.
[image]
And if click other item, it is working correctly now.

Comment: Which page or menu are you trying to access in admin? Verify your action url in menu.xml, controller path and your module admin's routes.xml. Refer this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316579/magento-2-custom-grid-action-404-error-add-action-throws-404-error

Comment: Turn on General Log, Login again as admin, turn off General Log and analyze the General Log to find the cause of the 404.

Comment: How can I turn on General log

Comment: Search in Google for 'mysql turn on General Log', please.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the url you are accessing.

I think you are going to a custom page and not to the magento dashboard!

This is magento dashboard url.
[image]